# Powerpoint loop through line charts - Active X Error

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I've made a code to open Powerpoint from excel, and loop through all the slides, find the graph and change some columns. I have the code for doing the replacement but cant' seem to loop through the slides because it throws an ActiveX error 429 that is basically saying that powerpoint is not found :O.

```
Sub pptDataChange()    

'Define variables of excel
Dim mySheet As Excel.Worksheet

'Define variables to open on PPT
Dim PowerPointApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim myPresentation As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim sld As Slide
Dim shp As Shape
Dim chrt As Chart

'Copy range from Excel
Set mySheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

'Create instance of Powerpoint
On Error Resume Next

    'Open Powerpoint with Powerpoint is already opened
    Set PowerPointApp = GetObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")

    'Clear errors
    Err.Clear

    'If Powerpoint is closed, open Powerpoint
    If PowerPointApp Is Nothing Then
        Set PowerPointApp = CreateObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")
    End If

    'Handle error if Powerpoint isn't installed or not found
    If Err.Number = 429 Then
        MsgBox ("PowerPoint not found, aborting...")
        Exit Sub
    End If

On Error GoTo 0

'Make Powerpoint visible and active
PowerPointApp.Visible = True
PowerPointApp.Activate

'Open Powerpoint Presentation from PATH and set it as the active
PowerPointApp.Presentations.Open ("File.pptx")

For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each shp in sld
       'Iterate through charts and change data of chart using something like If sld Has.Chart Then ...
Next sld

Exit Sub
```

What I'm thinking is that maybe it's because of the ActivePresentation, but I've tried referencing to `myPresentation` but It was the same.

Can you please help?

Comment: Which line is throwing the error?

Comment: `For each sld in ActivePresentation.Slides`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I explicitly declared a `Presentation` variable to use instead of `ActivePresentation` and that seemed to do the trick. FYI: I also changed the declarations for the `sld` and `shp` variables to explicitly reference the PowerPoint object library.

```
Sub pptDataChange()

'Define variables of excel
Dim mySheet As Excel.Worksheet

'Define variables to open on PPT
Dim PowerPointApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim myPresentation As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim sld As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim shp As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim chrt As Chart

'Copy range from Excel
Set mySheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

'Create instance of Powerpoint
On Error Resume Next

    'Open Powerpoint with Powerpoint is already opened
    Set PowerPointApp = GetObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")

    'Clear errors
    Err.Clear

    'If Powerpoint is closed, open Powerpoint
    If PowerPointApp Is Nothing Then
        Set PowerPointApp = CreateObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")
    End If

    'Handle error if Powerpoint isn't installed or not found
    If Err.Number = 429 Then
        MsgBox ("PowerPoint not found, aborting...")
        Exit Sub
    End If

On Error GoTo 0

'Make Powerpoint visible and active
PowerPointApp.Visible = True
PowerPointApp.Activate

'Open Powerpoint Presentation from PATH and set it as the active
Dim pres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Set pres = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Open("File.pptx")

For Each sld In pres.Slides
    For Each shp In sld.Shapes
       'Iterate through charts and change data of chart using something like If sld Has.Chart Then ...
    Next shp
Next sld

End Sub
```